# Fixed Sidebar Scrolling and Stop at Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Creating a fixed sidebar that stops at bottom of parent div. The issue I am having is when the fixed sidebar starts immediately on scroll and it should start and stay right below the header about 30px and then when it reaches the bottom it should stay at the bottom of parent.

Right now it starts as soon as you scroll and then when reaching the bottom it kicks up.

You can see my pen here: https://codepen.io/chuckers82/pen/mdbvZYR

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $(".faqnav > div").css("position", "fixed");
    $(".faqnav > div").css("top", "");
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
    $(".faqnav > div").css("position", "");
    $(".faqnav > div").css("top", "");
  }
  if (
    $(".faqnav > div").offset().top + $(".faqnav > div").height() >
    $("#backup").offset().top
  ) {
    $(".faqnav > div").css(
      "top",
      -(
        $(".faqnav > div").offset().top +
        $(".faqnav > div").height() -
        $("#backup").offset().top
      )
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you want the sidebar stay below header or can you a bit more clear

Comment: Yes stay below the header by maybe 30px;

Comment: I have added some modifications to your code to fix the sidebar below header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some modification to your code so that the sidebar that is Faq session will stay below the header on scroll

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
    $(".faqnav > div").css("position", "fixed");
    $(".faqnav > div").css("top", "90px");
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
    $(".faqnav > div").css("position", "");
    $(".faqnav > div").css("top", "");
  }
  if (
    $(".faqnav > div").offset().top + $(".faqnav > div").height() >
    $("#backup").offset().top
  ) {

    $(".faqnav > div").css("position", "sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
}
.spud {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.faqs {
  padding: 90px;
      Padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.faqs > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.faqs > div > div.faqnav {
  width: 25%;
}
.faqs > div > div.faqnav > div {
  padding: 0 30px 0 12px;
}
.faqs > div > div.faqnav > div a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
.faqs > div > div.faqnav > div a.heyo {
  color: #2880f8;
}
.faqs > div > div.faqnav > div a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 3px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #999;
  left: -10px;
}
.faqs > div > div.faqnav > div a.heyo:before {
  background: #2880f8;
}
.faqs > div > div.faqnav > div a.heyo:focus:before {
}
.faqs > div > div.faqwrap {
  width: 75%;
}
p.toggle {
  color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
p.toggle:before {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #2880f8;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
p.toggle.active {
  color: #2880f8;
}
p.toggle.active:before {
  content: "\f107";
}
.accordion {
  height: 500px;
}
.accordion:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.accordion .inner {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.accordion .inner ol,
.accordion .inner ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.accordion:first-child {
  background: #fafafa;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.accordion:nth-child(2) {
  background: #fafafa;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.accordion:nth-child(3) {
  background: #fafafa;
}
.accordion > div {
  padding: 50px;
}
.accordion > div h3 {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#backup {
  background: #000;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">NAV</header>
<section class="spud">
  <h1>FAQs</h1>
</section>
<section class="faqs">
  <div>
    <div class="faqnav">
      <div>
        <a href="#one" class="heyo">One</a>
        <a href="#two">Two</a>
        <a href="#three">Three</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="faqwrap">
      <div class="accordion" id="one">
        <div>
          <h3>One </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion" id="two">
        <div>
          <h3>Two</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion" id="three">
        <div>
          <h3>Three</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<div id="backup"></div>
```

Comment: It is not stopping at the bottom though, it still jumps when you get to the bottom.

Comment: @boloneysandwich I have updated my answer you can check it. It will stay till the faq's session active when the backup session comes it will stay at the faq's. I hope this is what you need. Or you need the sidebar needs to stay till the end of the page that means you need it to stay for backup div also ?